# Connect to AWS EC2 using IP Address

Tags: apache, http, amazon-web-services, telnet, iptables

I am trying to serve a website on AWS using Apache, something I have done before.  In this case I am not sure why I can't connect.

My security group settings allow connections on port 80, 22, 443, 27017.

The output of netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN is:

> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
>   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
>   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
>   tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
>   tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN

The output of sudo iptables -L is:

> Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
>   target     prot opt source               destination
>   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:http
>   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
>   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
>   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
>
> Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
>   target     prot opt source               destination
>
> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
>   target     prot opt source               destination

When I telnet the IP address and port 22 I am able to connect, I can also SSH into the box.  When I telnet the IP address and port 80 or 443 the connection is refused.

What am I missing?

Comment: First, are you sure the security group allows connections on ports 80 and 433 from source 0.0.0.0/0? If that is ok, is your EC2 inside a VPC? How is the security group for the VPC?

Comment: The security group settings are:Ports Protocol Source eddy-wptest
80 tcp 0.0.0.0/0 ✔
2368 tcp 0.0.0.0/0 ✔
22 tcp 0.0.0.0/0 ✔
27017 tcp 0.0.0.0/0 ✔
443 tcp 0.0.0.0/0 ✔

Comment: How about your public ip address? Is that well configure?

Answer (score 0):

From your information, you only allow the port 80 connection via IPv6.
So even if you have port 80 listening, you cannot telnet the HTTP(port 80) and HTTPS(port 443) via IPv4 address successfully.

I suggest you reference to this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/bind.html

Make sure your have the something like this in your httpd.conf file:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
```